# Angular 2 - Dynamically changing URL (in the address bar)

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I came across this behaviour in the ESPN website and was wondering how to achieve that using Angular2. When I am reading an article there, as soon as the article is done, the next article loads and the URL in the address bar changes automatically. Once I scroll back up to the old article, the URL changes again to the old one. 
For example, take this link.

http://www.espn.in/football/barclays-premier-league/23/blog/post/3017450/phil-jones-and-henrikh-mkhitaryan-in-team-of-the-weekend

This is just a random article from the site. You can check the behavior mentioned above there. I also saw that the ESPN website was not built with Angular 2.

Still, I was just wondering if I wanted to do this using Angular2, how do I proceed? That is, to change the URL in the address bar on scrolling through a page or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone is still looking to solve this.

This is what I ended up doing then. Going through the documentation, I realised that when a router navigates to a route that renders the same component, the component isn't initialised again.

Let us say you have this route that renders the ItemComponent.

```
item/:id
```

When you are navigate like this.

```
item/3 -> item/4
```

The component does not get initialised again.
I leveraged this and depending on my current position in the page, I navigated to the URL I wanted in the address bar. 
It does not sound entirely convincing, but it does work.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have two choices, using hash ( # ) or not using it :).

In order to not use the hash, you'd need to tell your server to re-route all the request to index.html otherwise it won't work.

And you'd need to say :

```
 RouterModule.forRoot( ROUTES , { useHash : false } )
```

Comment: I can understand what you mean. But I dont think that is what I am looking for. Maybe I haven't framed the question correctly. Check that link out. You will understand what I am looking to achieve. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: I just read your question and my answer again, no idea why I have said this : :D:PDD: it's totally unrelated, I might have been drunk or something :)

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate the current anchor as you want in Javascript without reloading the page. So, when you're setting your url with :

```
location.href = location.href+ "#1234";
```

You won't reload the page until "1234" means something for the router.

Comment: But this means we need the '#' right? Basically moving inside the same page. However, check that link, when you scroll to a new article, the entire URL changes as well as the title of the page. That's the part I was wondering about.